# How to manually get a kerberos service ticket?

Tags: windows-7, kerberos

I've registred a SPN, now I want to try to get a ticket for it.
I know there is linux kvno to do that is there an analog on windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux you can use "kinit" to verify specified SPN. This tool creates a Kerberos AS-ticket and stores it in a cache. Because of security reasons, this cache is meant to be used by operating system components.

To have kinit in Windows I install latest Java JDK (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
Syntax: `kinit <SPN>`. Application will ask you for the password. If you'd enter correct password, you'll have AS-ticket created and stored in Kerberos cache.

Then you may list content of Kerberos cache, using `klist -c`.

Comment: The source code for the Java `kinit` implementation is currently available here https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/security/krb5/internal/tools/Kinit.java#L142

Comment: kinit gets you a TGT instead of a service ticket.  See @markus-kuhn's answer about "klist get" instead.

Answer (score 3):

The windows equivalent to `kinit` for realm `CORP.CONTOSO.COM` is:

1. Add the SAMAccountName as the user credentials for the realm in `Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials`
   [image: Image of credential manager]
   **Note 1:** you must use the realm exactly.  You cannot use the domain name or a UPN. E.g.: `CORP.CONTOSO.COM\jsmith` is fine, but `CORP\jsmith` and `john@contoso.com` will fail.
   **Note 2:** This can alternately be done using `cmdkey /add:*.CORP.CONTOSO.COM /user:CORP.CONTOSO.COM\jsmith /pass`
   **Note 3:** These saved credentials are retained indefinitely in your roaming profile.  Remove them afterwards if this is not desired.
2. Make the connection to the service (using ssh, CIFS, RDP/TERMSERV, etc…) and verify a service ticket was created using `klist`.  Alternately you can request a ticket explicitly using `klist get SPN` (e.g.: for CIFS on dc1 with `klist get cifs/dc1.CORP.CONTOSO.COM`)

Alternately, you can use runas for temporary connections (avoiding saved creds in credential manager):

1. Use `runas /netonly /user:CORP.CONTOSO.COM\jsmith cmd` to start `cmd` with a new access token
2. Make the connection to the service and verify kerberos auth succeeded with `klist`

Related:

- [Discussions on WinOpenSSH github](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1295#issuecomment-847001097)
- [Super User
  Windows: Obtain Kerberos TGT from another principal](https://superuser.com/questions/442958/windows-obtain-kerberos-tgt-from-another-principal)

Answer (score 2):

Try `klist get SPN` as per [Microsoft’s klist documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/klist).

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos tickets can be generated using ktpass aswell.
On windows prompt (Assumed KDC is installed)

```
ktpass -out <file>.keytab -mapuser <username>@REALM-IN-CAPS  -pass <of-user>  -crypto all  -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL  -princ spn-of-user@REALM-IN-CAPS
```

This will generate `*.keytab` in current working directory.

Comment: `ktpass` is used to create keytab files (which contain pairs of SPNs and password hashes). That is not the same thing as a Kerberos ticket.